# How many different sets of positive numbers have the sum of its elements equal to n?

Tags: combinatorics

The sets of number must satisfy the following conditions:

1. The sum of numbers in it must equal to $N$.
2. Each numbers can only appear once or less in the set.
3. Sets must contain $2$ or more positive integer number.

For example
If $N = 5$ there are $2$ sets : $(1,4)$ and $(2,3)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that your question currently doesn't show any effort on your part to solve this problem, which puts off most people around here. You should improve it by telling us how you tried to solve it.

Comment: Do there have to be at least two elements in each set?  For instance for your example with $N=5$, should $\{5\}$ count as a possible set?

Comment: Also: by "numbers" do you mean integers? Otherwise the answer is infinitely many, e.g. for $N=1$ you have $\{\frac{1}{N}, \frac{N-1}{N}\}$. Furthermore, *sets* are unordered by definition, so condition 3 is always true.

Comment: Sorry for all my mistakes. The set must contain >= 2 positive integer number. And this is my informatics problem, i solved it but my solution was too slow. So i tried to find a formula for it, but my math is not really good. I really need helps with this problem.

Comment: Your number is $1$ less than the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. The theory is rather complicated, as a start you may want to look at [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: I found a website with the formula related to this problem : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html